# Jquery resizable: как определить с какой стороны элемента сделан resize

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, javascript

```
resizable.handles = 'n, e, s, w'
```

Как в событии resizable.stop определить, за какую гранизу тянул пользователь?
Это можно сделать только вычислением координат текущей позиции из координат начальной позиции или можно как-то проще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уж не знаю, насколько это будет проще, но пришел в голову такой вариант: во время начала ресайза, к элементу добавляется класс, в зависимости от того, за какую границу мы "ухватились": **ui-resizable-{direction}** (где *direction* - это символ handles). Посему, мы [можем использовать эту особенность](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/3AJsf/). Обращу внимание, что пример с учетом того, что используются стандартные handles и в данном случае - только те, что вы перечислили! В противном случае, надо учитывать, что handles может состоять из нескольких символов (*ne, se, sw, nw, all*) или же используются какие-то дополнительные классы. Тогда нужно будет продумать, как получать нужный класс и, соответственно, из него значение направления.